# with open(file) in except

Tags: python, python-2.7

In a try...except block i want to log the Exception error message to a file in the except path.

```
try:
   doc = etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
except Exception, e:

   print '%s: %s' % (e, url)
   with open('error.txt', 'a') as f:
     f.write('%s:%s\n' % url, e)
   return
```

The print shows the error, but the with open ... f.write is not excecuted.

in the same script the relaxng validation is written to file

```
if not RELAXNG.validate(doc):
  with open('error.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('%s\n' % RELAXNG.error_log)
  return
```

Can somebody explain to me, why

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'a') as f
  f.write( ...
```

is posible in the *if* statement, but not in an *except*?

Comment: Consider using [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`write()` does not accept multiple arguments; you are probably missing parenthesis:

```
f.write('%s:%s\n' % (url, e))
```

Other than that, use *absolute* paths, not relative, as you can easily write the file in an unexpected place otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

File operations inside `except` works fine.

```
>>> try:
    raise SyntaxError("Hello")
except Exception:
    with open("in.txt") as f:
        print "F"


F
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Try this for example:

```
try:
    raise Exception
except Exception:
    with open('error.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('foobar')
```

If you run the above you will see foobar been written to file.

Is error.txt writeable by your process? There is some reason it's not writing to your file but it's not because the 'with' file context isn't allowed inside an except block.